# HDPI and MDPI Problem

Tags: android

All these days i used to test my application on my HTC Legend (2.1 OS) only, and i had all my images resources in drawable-hdpi folder.. and everything worked fine

and today i wanted to test my Application on Android 1.5, so i recreated all the images with lower resolution and kept it under drawable-mdpi folder, so now i have High resolution images in drawable-hdpi folder and lower resolution images in drawable-mdpi folder..

Everything looked great on both the HTC Legend and Emulator(with Android 1.5)

Later i found out that the images in drawable-mdpi are shown in my HTC Legend too and not the images in drawable-hdpi

in my manifest file i have also included

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Can anyone help me with this, I want to know as to why the images in drawable-hdpi are not used?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing

```
 <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />
```

UPD:

Just noticed that Legend is MDPI device (Resolution: 320 X 480 HVGA). So the question is incorrect, your application behaves as it is expected to behave.

Look at the section https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range to become educated on android device sizes and densities.

Comment: Have you tried also to add target sdk version as @Rahul advices? Probably set it to 7 or even 8.

Comment: Sorry, it didnt work, 

I have an image x.png in  drawable-mdpi (red in color)
and I have an image x.png in  drawable-hdpi (blue in color)

Expecting the blue color'd image to load in my HTC Legend (2.1) and Red Color'd image in Emulator (OS 1.5)

Comment: Why do you expect hdpi image on Legend? Legend is mdpi device.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, HTC Legend is a MDPI device and i was expecting the HDPI images to load.

I created an emulator with Nexus1 Config, and it picked up the images in HDPI folder

And for 1.5 OS, I moved all the images from MDPI folder to Drawable folder.

So now i have HD images in drawable-hdpi folder
No images in drawable-mdpi folder
Moved all my images in drawable-mdpi folder to drawable folder.

and added <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" /> in my manifest file..

Now my app looks good on all the Android phones i have tested on and picking up the correct images as i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding

```
android:targetSdkVersion="4"
```

and remove the `anyDensity` tag.

Comment: Tryed it now, and it did not work ..

I have an image x.png in  drawable-mdpi (red in color)
and I have an image x.png in  drawable-hdpi (blue in color)

Expecting the blue color'd image to load in my HTC Legend (2.1) and Red Color'd image in Emulator (OS 1.5)

Comment: Then better create a folder called drawable in res dir and put your images related to 1.5 there. I think android should automatically use it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that the images are not always updated 'live'. Uninstalling the app using ADB is not successful in updating the images (in folders ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xdpi).

Sometimes, a phone restart is needed before the images are refreshed. Seems like there is a cache in the phone to store these images, even after uninstalling.